# Socket library, connect to site and print its contents

Tags: lua

I just made a simple site [testingtest.comyr.com](http://testingtest.comyr.com) (.php file just contains an echo "Hello, world!";) hosted from site [www.000webhost.com](http://www.000webhost.com) and I all I want is to print the contents written on this (the "Hello, world!" text). The code I use (**Please notice that I can only use "socket" library to my project**):

```
sok1 = require("socket")

Host = "testingtest.comyr.com"
Link = "/"

sok2 = sok1.connect(Host, 80)
sok2:send("GET "..Link.." HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")
receive = sok2:receive('*a')
print(receive)
```

but this gives me:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 01 Oct 2014 17:03:01 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://error404.000webhost.com/?
Content-Length: 216
Connection: close
Connection-type: text/hmtl; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCUMENT HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
The document has moved here.

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting back `302` status with the `Location` header, which indicates a redirect, and a new URL you are being redirected to. Since you are using raw socket module, it doesn't handle redirects; you either need to use `socket.http` module that handles that for you or to write some logic that parses the response to find `Location` header if you get any of 3xx codes and then repeats the request with the new URL.

Given that the redirected URL is `error404.000webhost.com` (404 indicates "page not found"), it's also possible you made some mistake in deploying the PHP page you put together.

Something like this may be able to handle redirect (if you can only use "socket" library per your comment):

```
sok1 = require("socket")
Host = "testingtest.comyr.com"
Link = "/"

local hosts = {}
while true do
  sok2 = sok1.connect(Host, 80)
  sok2:send("GET "..Link.." HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: "..Host.."\r\n\r\n")
  receive = sok2:receive('*a')
  -- check if this is a redirect
  if receive:find("^HTTP/1%.%d 3%d%d") then
    local host, link = receive:match("Location: http://([^/\r\n]+)(/?[^\r\n]*)")
    if host and link and not hosts[host] then
      Host, Link = host, #link > 0 and link or "/"
      hosts[host] = true -- keep track of redirects to avoid loops
      print("redirecting to", host..link)
    end
  else
    break -- done
  end
end  
print(#receive)
```

The logic checks for loops, but it only handles redirect to `http:` URLs (you'd need to check for https and change port 80 to 443). I also added the `Host` header as it otherwise may not work with some ISP providers that host multiple domains on the same IP address.

Comment: For some project reasons, I am allowed to use only the "socket" library. I test the above code on random sites and it gives pretty much same results tho :/ thanks for your reply

Comment: Your next best bet is probably to parse the returned page and grab the URL from the Location header.

Comment: thanks for your answer. had figured it out that I gotta use "HTTP/1.0\r\nHost:" but I had already started the bounty :P thanks for your answer tho, helped my figure out some other stuff as well. I will wait one or two more days and I will accept your answer :)